# How do I change a listbox view in my python Tkinter project to a tree view

Tags: python, tkinter, tkintertable

I tried to use tree view to display the data of my project output but consistently got below error for all the button clicks[image]

I then switched to Listbox view and I was able to execute my project with no errors, all data being displayed, scrollbar working and select working perfectly.

How I want to use the tree view and also get it to work with selection and scrollbar.
If anyone can assist correct my code to use the tree view instead and point out my mistakes. I have commented the tree view code.

```
from tkinter import *
from app_backend import Database
from tkinter import ttk
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="usrname",
            password="",database="database",connect_timeout=10)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM property_damage_claim")
        self.conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        #we will leave the database open here.

    
    
    
    
    def insert(self,clf_name,cll_name,contact,policy,Insurance,in_contact,status):
        self.conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO property_damage_claim VALUES (
        NULL,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(clf_name,cll_name,contact,policy,
        Insurance,in_contact,status))
        self.conn.commit()

    def view(self):
        self.conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM property_damage_claim")
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows


    def search(self,clf_name ='',cll_name ='',contact ='',policy='',Insurance='',in_contact='',status=''):
        self.conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM property_damage_claim WHERE clf_name=%s OR 
        cll_name=%s OR contact=%s OR policy=%s OR Insurance=%s OR in_contact=%s OR 
        status=%s",(clf_name,cll_name,contact,policy,Insurance,in_contact,status))
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows


    def delete(self,id):
        self.conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM property_damage_claim WHERE id=%s",(id,))
        self.conn.commit()


    def update(self,id,clf_name,cll_name,contact,policy,Insurance,in_contact,status):
        self.conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        self.cur.execute("UPDATE property_damage_claim SET clf_name=%s, cll_name=%s, contact=%s, 
        policy=%s, Insurance=%s, in_contact=%s, status=%s WHERE id=%s",(clf_name,cll_name,
        contact,policy,Insurance,in_contact,status,id))
        self.conn.commit()
        
        

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()
    
        







db = Database()

def selected_row(event):
    try:
        global selected_content
        index = student_list.curselection()[0]
        selected_content = student_list.get(index)
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e1.insert(END,selected_content[1])

        e2.delete(0,END)
        e2.insert(END,selected_content[2])

        e3.delete(0,END)
        e3.insert(END,selected_content[3])

        e4.delete(0,END)
        e4.insert(END,selected_content[4])

        e5.delete(0,END)
        e5.insert(END,selected_content[5])

        e6.delete(0,END)
        e6.insert(END,selected_content[6])

        e7.delete(0,END)
        e7.insert(END,selected_content[7])
    except IndexError:
        pass

# connecting the backend functions
def view_all():
    student_list.delete(0,END)
    for row in db.view():
        student_list.insert(END,row)

def search_record():
    student_list.delete(0,END)
    for row in db.search(clf_name.get(),cll_name.get(),contact.get(),
    policy.get(),Insurance.get(),in_contact.get(),status.get()):
        student_list.insert(END,row)
        
        
def add_record():
    try:
        if cll_name.get():
            db.insert(clf_name.get(),cll_name.get(),contact.get(),policy.get(),
            Insurance.get(),in_contact.get(),status.get())
            student_list.delete(0,END)
            student_list.insert(END,(clf_name.get(),cll_name.get(),contact.get(),
            policy.get(),Insurance.get(),in_contact.get(),status.get()))
            e1.delete(0,END)
            e2.delete(0,END)
            e3.delete(0,END)
            e4.delete(0,END)
            e5.delete(0,END)
            e6.delete(0,END)
            e7.delete(0,END)
    except:
        print("tcl Error")

def delete_record():
    db.delete(selected_content[0])
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e2.delete(0,END)
    e3.delete(0,END)
    e4.delete(0,END)
    e5.delete(0,END)
    e6.delete(0,END)
    e7.delete(0,END)
    

    view_all()


def update_record():
    db.update(selected_content[0],clf_name.get(),cll_name.get(),
    contact.get(),policy.get(),Insurance.get(),in_contact.get(),status.get())
    view_all()

def new_record():
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e2.delete(0,END)
    e3.delete(0,END)
    e4.delete(0,END)
    e5.delete(0,END)
    e6.delete(0,END)
    e7.delete(0,END)
    


window = Tk()

window.geometry("1000x2000")

bg = PhotoImage(file = "bgg.gif")

label1 = Label( window, image = bg)
label1.place(x = 0, y = 0)



window.wm_title("Goodwill Brokers")

wr1=LabelFrame(window, text="")
wr2=LabelFrame(window, text="Client Data")
wr3=LabelFrame(window, text="Search")
wr4=LabelFrame(window, text="Client List")

wr1.pack(fill="both", expand="no", padx="20", pady="10")
wr2.pack(fill="both", expand="no", padx="20", pady="10")
wr3.pack(fill="both", expand="no", padx="20", pady="10")
wr4.pack(fill="both", expand="no", padx="20", pady="10")

# GUI Components
#  Labels 
lb_title = ttk.Label(wr1,text="Goodwill Brokers".upper())
lb_title.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,pady=15)




lb_date = ttk.Label(wr2,text="First Name:")
lb_date.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky="e")

lb_sname = ttk.Label(wr2,text="Last Name:")
lb_sname.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky="e")

lb_grade = ttk.Label(wr2,text="Contact:")
lb_grade.grid(row=6,column=0,sticky="e")

lb_class = ttk.Label(wr2,text="Policy:")
lb_class.grid(row=7,column=0,sticky="e")

lb_pname = ttk.Label(wr2,text="Insurance:")
lb_pname.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky="e")

lb_psign = ttk.Label(wr2,text="Contact Person/Entity:")
lb_psign.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky="e")

lb_cin = ttk.Label(wr2,text="Status:")
lb_cin.grid(row=6,column=2,sticky="e")



# Entries

clf_name = StringVar()
e1 = ttk.Entry(wr2,textvariable= clf_name)
e1.grid(row =4,column=1)

cll_name = StringVar()
e2 = ttk.Entry(wr2,textvariable= cll_name)
e2.grid(row =5,column=1)

contact = StringVar()
e3 = ttk.Entry(wr2,textvariable= contact)
e3.grid(row =6,column=1)

policy = StringVar()
e4 = ttk.Entry(wr2,textvariable= policy)
e4.grid(row =7,column=1)

Insurance = StringVar()
e5 = ttk.Entry(wr2,textvariable= Insurance)
e5.grid(row =4,column=3)

in_contact = StringVar()
e6 = ttk.Entry(wr2,textvariable= in_contact)
e6.grid(row =5,column=3)

status = StringVar()
e7 = ttk.Entry(wr2,textvariable= status)
e7.grid(row =6,column=3)


# Buttons 

b1 = ttk.Button(wr3,text="View All", width=23,command=view_all)
b1.grid(row=8,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky="e",padx=10,pady=6)

b2 = ttk.Button(wr3,text="Search", width=23,command=search_record)
b2.grid(row=8,column=2,columnspan=2,sticky="w",padx=10,pady=6)

b3 = ttk.Button(wr3,text="Add", width=23,command=add_record)
b3.grid(row=9,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky="e",padx=10,pady=6)

b4 = ttk.Button(wr3,text="Update", width=23,command=update_record)
b4.grid(row=9,column=2,columnspan=2,sticky="w",padx=10,pady=6)

b5 = ttk.Button(wr3,text="Delete", width=23,command=delete_record)
b5.grid(row=10,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky="e",padx=10,pady=6)

b6 = ttk.Button(wr3,text="Close", width=23,command=window.destroy)
b6.grid(row=11,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=E,padx=10,pady=6)

b7 = ttk.Button(wr3,text="Clear", width=23,command=new_record)
b7.grid(row=10,column=2,columnspan=2,sticky="w",padx=10,pady=6)


# Listbox and scrollbar 

student_list= Listbox(wr4,height=6,width=60)
student_list.grid(row=12,column=0,rowspan=6,columnspan=3,sticky=E,padx=10,pady=10)

''' student_list = ttk.Treeview(wr4, columns=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), show='headings')
student_list.grid()

student_list.column("#1", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("#1", text="ID")

student_list.column("#2", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("#2", text="FNAME")

student_list.column("#3", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("#3", text="LNAME")

student_list.column("#4", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("#4", text="LNAME")

student_list.column("#5", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("#5", text="LNAME")

student_list.column("#6", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("#6", text="LNAME")

student_list.column("#7", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("#7", text="LNAME")

'''

sb1 = Scrollbar(wr4)
sb1.grid(row=12,column=3,rowspan=6,sticky=W)

student_list.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=student_list.yview)

# get the selected row from Listox to use Delete and Update Commands
student_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',selected_row)

window.resizable(0,0)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out after a few research here and there. You need to first create the tree view below

## Create a Treeview Scrollbar

```
tree_scroll = Scrollbar(wr4)
tree_scroll.grid(row=12,column=3,rowspan=6,sticky=W)

# Create The Treeview

student_list = ttk.Treeview(wr4, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set, 
selectmode="extended",show='headings')
student_list.grid()

# Configure the Scrollbar

tree_scroll.config(command=student_list.yview)

# Define Our Columns

student_list['columns'] = ("ID", "F_Name", "L_Name", "Contact", 
"Policy", "Insurance", "Contact P/E", "Status")

# Format Our Columns

student_list.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
student_list.column("ID", anchor=W, width=50)
student_list.column("F_Name", anchor=W, width=80)
student_list.column("L_Name", anchor=CENTER, width=80)
student_list.column("Contact", anchor=CENTER, width=120)
student_list.column("Policy", anchor=CENTER, width=120)
student_list.column("Insurance", anchor=CENTER, width=120)
student_list.column("Contact P/E", anchor=CENTER, width=120)
student_list.column("Status", anchor=CENTER, width=150)


# Create Headings

student_list.heading("#0", text="", anchor=W)
student_list.heading("ID", text="ID", anchor=W)
student_list.heading("F_Name", text="F_Name", anchor=W)
student_list.heading("L_Name", text="L_Name", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("Contact", text="Contact", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("Policy", text="Policy", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("Insurance", text="Insurance", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("Contact P/E", text="Contact P/E", anchor=CENTER)
student_list.heading("Status", text="Status", anchor=CENTER)
```

and then create a function to displace this, using a loop.

```
def view_all():
    for record in student_list.get_children():
        student_list.delete(record)
    for row in db.view():
        
        student_list.insert(parent='', index='end', text='', values=. 
        (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], 
        row[7]))
```

calling the database class

```
class Database:
    def view(self):
        self.conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM property_damage_claim")
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows
```